# Is this nesting of HTML elements invalid or semantically incorrect? main > section > header > h1

Tags: html, header, semantics, semantic-markup, article

I submitted a solution on a front-end component and I was told that the header should not have H1s within it, that it is a landmark outside the main tag and it has a "banner" role meaning it is for repeating content across a site.

I tried researching on AI tools, but I got different information.

Here is what I tried. I was building out a card component.

```html
<main>
   <section>
      <header>
            <h1 class="order-summary">Order Summary</h1>

            <p class="order-summary-text">
              You can now listen to millions of songs, audiobooks, and podcasts
              on any device anywhere you like!
            </p>
      </header>
   </section>
</main>
```

Comment: What you were told is incorrect. While heading elements don't have to be placed in `<header>` elements, they absolutely can be. And `<header>` isn't given the role of "banner" if it's a descendent of the main element or a few other sectioning roots. Assuming there's more content below the header in your section, your example is semantically acceptable. Refer to the HTML spec or the MDN Web Docs page on the [`<header>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) as authoritative sources for this info.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sean. I got a little confused. but now I am assured of what to do